# Tomahawk : t:outputText not working

Tags: jsf-1.2, tomahawk

Am using `JSF 1.2` and am trying to implement `Captcha` as per this [link](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/tomahawk_in_action_1.html)

So, my first objective is to get "Hello world" text using `t:outputText` to check if `Tomahawk` is working fine or not. My `JSF 1.2` based `Servlet` deploys fine in `Jboss AS 5.1.0`. But, when I hit my `Servlet`, nothing is getting displayed on the page. Nor there are any `Exceptions` in the logs.

Below is my `xhtml` page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

<ui:composition>
<head>  
 <title>CAPTCHA</title>   
</head>
<body>
<h:form id="captchatest">
<t:outputText value="This text is coming from tomahawk"></t:outputText>
</h:form>
</body>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Am using below `jars` in `WEB-INF/lib`

```
batik-awt-util-1.6-1.jar,
batik-ext-1.6-1.jar,
batik-gui-util-1.6-1.jar,
batik-util-1.6-1.jar,
commons-beanutils.jar,
commons-codec-1.3.jar,
commons-collections.jar,
commons-digester.jar,
commons-el-1.0.jar,
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar,
commons-io-1.3.2.jar,
commons-logging.jar,
commons-validator.jar,
el-ri.jar,
itext-1.4.8.jar,
jsf-api-1.2_13.jar,
jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar,
jsf-impl-1.2_13.jar,
myfaces.jar,
oro-2.0.8.jar,
standard-1.1.2.jar,
tomahawk-1.1.6.jar
```

I have below entry in `faces-config.xml`

```
 <application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
        <locale-config />
    </application>
```

When I view the `page source` in Browser, I just get whatever contents are there in my xhtml page instead of Tomahawk tags (t:outputText) getting parsed to HTML code.

Why am I not able to print the value of `t:outputText` in Browser?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing these jars 
        `el-ri.jar, oro-2.0.8.jar and standard-1.1.2.jar`

And I added this in xhtml page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```